# PUT request TypeError with firefox fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, fetch, put

```
fetch(URL + '/users/' + this.state.user.username, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.user)
})
```

this is giving me a 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.' in Firefox, but it works with Postman. I think it has to do with headers. Thanks!

Upon further testing, any PUT requests gives me the same error no matter what URL I pass it, even incorrect ones.

Comment: Could you add the specific TypeError is throwing?

Comment: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/310